# Mapping referenced table with C# automapper

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper, dto

Suppose I have a table `Scopes` which contains a foreign key to another table (`subscopes`) and I want to map it. All columns available in my `Scopes` table as well as some columns from my referenced table (`subscopes`) are required to be mapped to a DTO.

My questions are:

1. What should be the content of DTO?
2. How should I map using c# and Automapper?

Comment: 1. Content of DTO depend on your requiremts and preferences. 2. depends on DTO you've build

Comment: Any code you can show us? I have no idea which problem you're actually facing.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.CreateMap<tblSubScope, Sub2MainScopeDto>()
          .ForMember(t => t.IdxSubScope, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.idxSubScope))
          .ForMember(t => t.IdxMainScope, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.idxMainScope))
          .ForMember(t => t.SubScopeDescription, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.strSubScope))
          .ForMember(t => t.MainScopeDescription, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.tblMainScope.strMainScope))
          .ReverseMap()
          .ForMember(t => t.idxSubScope, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.IdxSubScope))
          .ForMember(t => t.strSubScope, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.SubScopeDescription))
          .ForMember(t => t.idxMainScope, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.IdxMainScope));
```

Problem Solved.